# Cannot read register values using pymodbus

Tags: python, pymodbus, smartmeter

When I tried the following code, I can connect to the smart meter, but I'm not able to read the register content.

```
import traceback
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.2.1', port=502)
client.connect()

try:
    res = client.read_holding_registers(0x0063, 1, unit=1)
    print(res.registers)

except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    
client.close()
```

The gives an exception

```
  Traceback <Most recent call last>
    File "m2.py", Line 8 ,in <module>
    print<res.registers>
AttributeErro: 'ModbusIOException' objecthas noattribute 'registers'
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: More information would help. Is there an exception? What is it? How do you know that you're connecting successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `client.connect` here

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
client = ModbusTcpClient(host='192.168.2.1', port=502)
client.connect() ### Added here

try:
   result = client.read_holding_registers(0x0063,1, unit=1)
   print (result.registers)

except Exception as e:
   print (e)

client.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , But when I tried your solution it gives and error like   ModusIoException ' Object has no attribute registers'  It will be great if you suggest a solution

Comment: @VijuPoonthottam - Can you post the `StackTrace` and update the question

Comment: @ Vaebhav   Edited and Posted

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar problem, `client.read_********` can return error without raising an exception.
So always check with `resp.isError()` and handle it.